# Cast a shadow with HDR world lighting?

Tags: shadows

I have quickly created a bed in Blender and I'm using HDR lighting on the World node in Cycles, is it possible to create a shadow underneath the bed without adding more 'light' to the object?

So basically, the bed looks exactly like the below but it has shadows cast underneath / around it.

[image: bed image]

Comment: Place a plane under the bed, so there is some geometry to cast the shadow on. You can also chcek shadow catcher in the object info tab to get only the shadow and not the actual plane

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to make the world lighting not cast shadows and then use a light source to cast shadows instead?