# How can I recreate this lighting?

Tags: lighting

We have had this bed created for us by a third party and I'm wondering if it is possible to recreate this lighting in Blender Cycles? I create simple bed mock ups from drawings and this would help tremendously in their presentation.

I have looked at various guides and tutorials but haven't found anything tailored to my needs.

[image: jcb junior bed]

Comment: what do you mean " recreate this lighting"?

Comment: There is barely any lighting to go by, that looks like a drop shadow edited in Photoshop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast a shadow with HDR world lighting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112809/cast-a-shadow-with-hdr-world-lighting)

Comment: @moonboots it looks like a 3D rendered model on a plain white background?

Comment: are you going to create a 3D object like this one? It can be either a transparent background and the white background + shadow can be created in photoshop, or create a white plane in Blender which is flat then goes up

Comment: @moonboots I do create 3d objects like the one above, if I were to use the white plane option, is there someway to make it just pure white without the shadows from lights etc affecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) With Blender (Cycles Render) and Photoshop you can do it this way:

- Create your object.
- Create a plane under your object. Keep this plane selected. In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Cycles Settings*, enable *Shadow Catcher*.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Render* > *Output* > Choose *PNG* and *RGBA* so that you can have a transparent channel, and in *Film* > enable *Transparent*.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Render* > click *Render*.
- Open your image with Photoshop, you have a PNG file with transparency and there is a shadow under your object.
- In Photoshop, put a white layer under the object layer.

2) As Risingfall says, if you know how the Compositing works, you won't need Photoshop, just use a white background and an Alpha Over node.

3) A more basic solution is to play in your 3D scene with a structure of planes that either have Diffuse shader so that they can receive shadow, or Emission shader, so that they stay 100% white.

Comment: Or you could use the compositor to create a white background, using the Alpha Over node.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's a little bit more complex though, as you need to know how the Compositing works

Comment: Thanks, I can get the object highlighted like the one above using emission planes but they create their own shadows so its hard to recreate the one like in the picture above unless I do photoshop trick like you suggested earlier

Comment: I would say that the Photoshop trick is the easiest, the Compositing is the most intelligent, and you can get what you want if you tinker a bit with Diffuse and Emission shaders